# Android Studio importing multiple project to function under main project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've made 3 different project called Task, Reminder and Main. I've created these project independently and I want project Task and Reminder to be able to view on Main project as a single project. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes..In android studio each independent project is termed as modules...and you can link these modules. These modules can been executed independently or combined as one

Comment: @ShadowDroid so I just import the module from the 2 project and it will function under Main project is that correct?

Comment: just importing won't do the work...you will have to link those modules as dependency in build.gradle of your main module.Check this link http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/library-project-module-as-dependency-in-android-studio

Comment: @ShadowDroid alright, thank you for the link and explanation mate